# Cloudflare worker strips headers

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I'm trying to migrate my CORS checker app from heroku to cloudflare workers as it seems to be a perfect fit for my use case.

The heroku app uses axios to asks a website for an options call to see if there are any headers with x-frame-options. If so, I check if it's denied, and return this as a boolean value in the REST response.

This sounds really simple, but I'm having trouble making it work on cloudflare workers. Am I correct in assuming that cloudflare is stripping these headers and there is no way to get this working with cloudflare workers?

Here is the full worker code

```
// node_modules/itty-router/dist/itty-router.mjs
var e = ({ base: e2 = "", routes: r = [] } = {}) => ({ __proto__: new Proxy({}, { get: (a, o, t) => (a2, ...p) => r.push([o.toUpperCase(), RegExp(`^${(e2 + a2).replace(/(\/?)\*/g, "($1.*)?").replace(/(\/$)|((?<=\/)\/)/, "").replace(/(:(\w+)\+)/, "(?<$2>.*)").replace(/:(\w+)(\?)?(\.)?/g, "$2(?<$1>[^/]+)$2$3").replace(/\.(?=[\w(])/, "\\.").replace(/\)\.\?\(([^\[]+)\[\^/g, "?)\\.?($1(?<=\\.)[^\\.")}/*$`), p]) && t }), routes: r, async handle(e3, ...a) {
  let o, t, p = new URL(e3.url), l = e3.query = {};
  for (let [e4, r2] of p.searchParams)
    l[e4] = void 0 === l[e4] ? r2 : [l[e4], r2].flat();
  for (let [l2, s, c] of r)
    if ((l2 === e3.method || "ALL" === l2) && (t = p.pathname.match(s))) {
      e3.params = t.groups || {};
      for (let r2 of c)
        if (void 0 !== (o = await r2(e3.proxy || e3, ...a)))
          return o;
    }
} });

// src/index.ts
var router = e();
var corsHeaders = {
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS",
  "Access-Control-Max-Age": "86400"
};
function jsonResponse(body) {
  return new Response(JSON.stringify(body), {
    status: 200,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    }
  });
}
function handleOptions(request) {
  let headers = request.headers;
  if (headers.get("Origin") !== null && headers.get("Access-Control-Request-Method") !== null && headers.get("Access-Control-Request-Headers") !== null) {
    let respHeaders = {
      ...corsHeaders,
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": request.headers.get("Access-Control-Request-Headers")
    };
    return new Response(null, {
      headers: respHeaders
    });
  } else {
    return new Response(null, {
      headers: {
        Allow: "GET, HEAD, POST, OPTIONS"
      }
    });
  }
}
router.options("/test-cors", async function(request) {
  return handleOptions(request);
});
router.post("/test-cors", async function(request) {
  const url = request.body.url;
  const externalRequest = new Request(url, { method: "head" });
  try {
    let response = await fetch(externalRequest);
    if (response.headers.get("x-frame-options") !== null) {
      const frameOptionsValue = response.headers.get("x-frame-options");
      if (frameOptionsValue === "SAMEORIGIN") {
        return jsonResponse({ canAccess: false });
      } else {
        return jsonResponse({ canAccess: true });
      }
    } else {
      return jsonResponse({ canAccess: true });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    if (error.code === "ENOTFOUND" || error.response.status === 404) {
      return jsonResponse({ canAccess: false, reason: "NOT_FOUND" });
    } else {
      return jsonResponse({ canAccess: false });
    }
  }
});
router.all("*", (request, args) => {
  return new Response("Not Found", {
    status: 404,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
      "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    }
  });
});
var src_default = {
  async fetch(request, env, ctx) {
    return router.handle(request);
  }
};
export {
  src_default as default
};
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

Comment: In what way is it not working, exactly? Cloudflare does not normally strip the "x-frame-options" header. The one exception is when running a preview next to the online editor, since the preview needs to run in an iframe, this header is stripped. That only applies to preview, though, not production, and it applies to the responses returned by the worker, whereas your code appears to care about the response from a subrequest (`fetch()` call). Possible issue: `const url = request.body.url` I believe request.body here is a stream object, it doesn't have a `url` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've talked with the developers behind the feature and it turns out the website I was trying to test for the header had a different behavior set for the calling IP.

Since the editor runs fetch from your browser the IP was different and was not triggering that effect.